# Eclipse Bitmap rendering in the debugger

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, bitmap

In `Android Studio` you can view bitmap in debugger as described [here](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio087released):

> While debugging, you can now right click on variables in your app that
>   are of type Bitmap, and invoke View Bitmap

[image]

Is there a way to do this in `Eclipse`?I do not want to save bitmap on SD Card.